# What does "Name seemed to be in doubt" mean in this context?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Hunger, chaos, thawed mud everywhere, uncollected debris, water
> pipes bursting, unofficial warnings of tainted water supplies, gas
> explosions. Unrest among Free Britons. Today being pay day, pay
> parades lined up punctually at FB centres at 09.00 hours. Moratorium
> on pay declared. No cash available. Violence. Arab leader spoke Oxford
> English at conference in Al-Dorchester ballroom (**Sheikh Isa Ta'ala?
> Name seemed to be in doubt)** about awareness of unpopularity of Arabs
> and Muslims generally in angry strikebound Britain, but Islam had
> known hostility throughout its long existence and there was no
> intention of withdrawal of Arab presence. Much Arab money tied up in
> British property.
>
> *- 1985 by ANthony burgess*

What does the author meany by saying: Name seemed to be in doubt? (emphasis in text is mine).

Answer (score 0):

The people present seemed to be unclear as to the speaker's correct name.

Comment: What do you mean by "people present"? Readers? Writer?

Comment: The people who were present at the conference where the Sheikh spoke.